# jQuery basic dialog not displaying

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery and trying to get a basic dialog to open when a link is clicked. The images you see in the Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cvh2013/ELZpt/) each function as a link. When clicked, the text linked to displays in a new browser tab but the dialog (which should contain the text linked to) is not generated. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, please?

CSS:

```
.circle {
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid #fff;
float: left;
display: inline-block;
/*margin-right: 20px;*/

/* text styling */
font-size: 45px;
color: #FFF;  
line-height: 250px;
text-align: center;
font-family: Ubuntu, sans-serif;
}

.industry { background: #DD4814; margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 5%; }
.in-house { background: #AEA79F; margin-left: 5%; margin-right: 10%; }
.lawfirms { background: #5E2750; margin-left: 16%; margin-right: 5%; }
.industry-box-shadow { box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #DD4814 }
.in-house-box-shadow { box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #AEA79F }
.lawfirms-box-shadow { box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #5E2750 }
.text { line-height: 45px; padding-top: 50px; height: 200px }

.loading { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -8px; margin-left: -8px;             }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sf">

    <a href="dialogcontent/lawfirms.html" title="Law firms">
        <div class="circle lawfirms lawfirms-box-shadow">Law firms</div>
    </a> 
    <a href="dialogcontent/industry.html" title="Industry">
        <div class="circle industry industry-box-shadow">Industry</div>
    </a> 
    <a href="dialogcontent/in-house.html" title="In-house legal counsel">
    <div class="circle in-house in-house-box-shadow text">In-house
            legal counsel</div> 
    </a>

</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    var $loading = $('<img src="images/loading.gif" alt="Loading ..." class="loading">');

    $('#sf a').each(function() {
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .append($loading.clone());
        var $link = $(this).one('click', function() {
            $dialog
                .load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
                .dialog({
                    title: $link.attr('title'),
                    width: 500,
                    height: 300
                });

            $link.click(function() {
                $dialog.dialog('open');

                return false;
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error, though it doesn't seem to be the entire problem: .one('click'

Comment: For some reason all your javascript libraries are not loading

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, you are just not allowed to load a page from another domain. (Also add the libraries via fiddle's interface and not directly linking them as those links seem broken)

Comment: Thank you Populus, I was adding the libraries using Fiddler's External Resource option which was wrong. Reagrding the cross-site issue - I put the loading.gif and the static HTMl on Ubuntu One file-sharing so the people seeing the Fiddle could get the full picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to load jQuery and jQuery UI in your fiddler, next you can't use `var $dialog` in the click event if its only defined in the `$.each`  see [here in the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELZpt/8/)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var $loading = $('<img src="http://ubuntuone.com/5qQ3i4ctM8HAvRsSIZKgqd" alt="Loading ..." class="loading">'); 
    var $dialog = $('<div></div>')

    $('#sf a').each(function () {

             $dialog.append($loading.clone());
        var $link = $(this).one('click', function () {
            $dialog.load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
                .dialog({
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: 500,
                height: 300
            });

            $link.click(function (e) {

            //    e.preventDefault();
                $dialog.dialog('open');

                return false;
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: sorry this is incorrect. this will end up all dialogs showing the data for the last dialog being initialized.

Comment: I just fixed enough for him to see the dialog comming up,  the title was "jQuery dialog not displaying"

Comment: Thank you Scott. It now works as expected in the Fiddler but not on my local machine so there must be some local issue I need to resolve.

Comment: @ClivevanHilten  - yup that will do it